# Split string into an array of string

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, string

I have a SIM900 module connected to an Arduino Uno, using an AT command for listing the SMS I get this output, how can i split this based on (`,`) to store each data in an array?

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"

+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","+639321576684","Ralph Manzano","16/04/25,21:51:33+32"
Yow!!!

OK
```

Comment: Since arduino is very limited in memory and available flash, I suggest you to avoid trying to split the whole line in chunks, but rather just take the segments you need. If you can't, then it would still be better not to store it, but rather analyze the segments one by one while you read them. Anyway I suggest you to parse the whole line one char at a time and check it, but be careful that there is a comma also between the date and the time, so if you don't want it to be split you should also group the parameters according to the double quotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to use `strtok`. Code from my mind and not tested:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char string[] = "AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"\n"
    "\n"
    "+CMGL: 2,\"REC READ\",\"+639321576684\",\"Ralph Manzano\",\"16/04/25,21:51:33+32\"\n"
    "Yow!!!\n"
    "\n"
    "OK\n";
    char delimiter[] = ",\n";

    // initialize first part (string, delimiter)
    char* ptr = strtok(string, delimiter);

    while(ptr != NULL) {
        printf("found one part: %s\n", ptr);
        // create next part
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Outputs:

```
found one part: AT+CMGL="ALL"
found one part: +CMGL: 2
found one part: "REC READ"
found one part: "+639321576684"
found one part: "Ralph Manzano"
found one part: "16/04/25
found one part: 21:51:33+32"
found one part: Yow!!!
found one part: OK
```

Comment: thank you so mcuh! but the strings may vary depending on the message sent, who sent the message and when it was sent, how can i parse this?

Comment: @Ralph I updated my answer. You can have multiple delimter. I think you should be able to parse all the needed information out of the string you get ;)

Comment: ohhh thank you! does this mean ill just store the response of the at command in the string[] array? and ill be able to parse it despite the content?

Comment: @Ralph imho yes

Comment: sorry im really new to parsing, will definitely try this, thanks!